# Kotlin Coroutines, retrofit-2.6.1, Network response null

Tags: android-studio, request, kotlin-coroutines, retrofit2.6

I am going through reso-coder `Weather app` tutorial. Most of the things changed with the passage of time, so is apixu weather website. 
Now it's the time of `Retrofit 2.6.1` which means `kotlin coroutines` 
 
The problem is that i am getting everything Null in network Response 
I have go through all data classes with SerializedName, everything seems pretty fine, still can't get the problem.. 
BTW i'm not using `ViewModel` right now just directly hoping into the fragment textView

```
interface ApixuWeatherApiService {


 @GET("current")
    suspend fun getCurrentWeather(
        @Query("query") location: String,
        @Query("lang") languageCode: String = "en"
    ): CurrentWeatherResponse

    //to handle this above interface we need companion object

    companion object WeatherAPis {
        private val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
            val url = chain.request()
                .url().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("access_key", API_KEY)
                .build()

            val request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        private val okHTTPClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(requestInterceptor).build()
        private fun retroFit(): Retrofit = Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .client(okHTTPClient)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val weatherApi: ApixuWeatherApiService =
            retroFit().create(ApixuWeatherApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Fragment Class

```
class CurrentWeatherFragment : Fragment() {


    private lateinit var viewModel: CurrentWeatherViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_weather_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CurrentWeatherViewModel::class.java)
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            widCOntext()
        }

    }


    private suspend fun widCOntext() {
        val apiService = ApixuWeatherApiService.weatherApi
            withContext(Main) {
                val currentWeatherResponse =
                    withContext(IO) {
                        apiService.getCurrentWeather(
                            "London"
                        )
                    }
                txtView.text = currentWeatherResponse.toString()
            }

    }
}
```

I have used plugin to convert JSON to kotlin file to get these
**Four data classes**
**Current**

```
data class Current(
    @SerializedName("observation_time")
    val observationTime: String,
    val temperature: Int,
    @SerializedName("weather_code")
    val weatherCode: Int,
    @SerializedName("weather_icons")
    val weatherIcons: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("weather_descriptions")
    val weatherDescriptions: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    val windSpeed: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_degree")
    val windDegree: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_dir")
    val windDir: String,
    val pressure: Int,
    val precip: Int,
    val humidity: Int,
    val cloudcover: Int,
    val feelslike: Int,
    @SerializedName("uv_index")
    val uvIndex: Int,
    val visibility: Int,
    @SerializedName("is_day")
    val isDay: String
)
```

**CurrentWeatherResponse**

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    val request: Request,
    val location: Location,
    val current: Current
)
```

**Location**

```
data class Location(
    val name: String,
    val country: String,
    val region: String,
    val lat: String,
    val lon: String,
    @SerializedName("timezone_id")
    val timezoneId: String,
    val localtime: String,
    @SerializedName("localtime_epoch")
    val localtimeEpoch: Int,
    @SerializedName("utc_offset")
    val utcOffset: String
)
```

**Request**

```
data class Request(
    val type: String,
    val query: String,
    val language: String,
    val unit: String
)
```

Comment: So it neither throws an Exception nor returns a result? Have you tried changing return type from CurrentWeatherResponse to Response<CurrentWeatherResponse> ?

Comment: nope. my _textView_ was just showing null, it was written **null** on _textView_. after changing to **Response<CurrentWeatherResponse>** it is showing some weird output like  `protocol=h2, code=200,message, url= websiteurl `

Comment: Could you try printing `response.body()` ? Also, how does your `CurrentWeatherResponse` class look like?

Comment: @r2rek yes i try to print `response.body()` and got the exact same **null** response. Here it is, `debug: CurrentWeatherResponse(request=null, location=null, current=null)` this is what i was getting in _textView_ .. BTW i have updated my question and added `data classes`.

Comment: I know this might seem silly, but try to remove `withContext(IO) ` - you don't need it when using suspend funs with retrofit.

Comment: @r2rek already tried it, just used `withContext(Main)` for main Thread(textView) and `CoroutineScope(IO).launch{}` in main function to call suspend function.. still same.

Comment: try adding an httpInterceptor and paste the result of request
https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: Solved! Look below...

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Solved** : I hope this gonna help someone 
 
Here what i did 
Whenever i stuck somewhere, i make new project and try to work on that specific thing. 
Now what i did over here which i think resolved my problem. 
I have used singleton pattern, I have made Singleton instance of **ApiService Interface**, before **singleton** it was showing response 200 but output was **null** as well and now just by making **singleton** it resolved my Problem and now i am getting desired output 
Here is code:

```
object RetrofitRequest {

    private val interceptor = Interceptor {chain ->
        val url = chain.request()
            .url()
            .newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("access_key/key", yourApiKey)
            .build()

        val request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build()

        return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
    }

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .build()

    @Volatile
    private var instance : ApiService? = null
    fun getInstance() : ApiService = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        instance ?: fullResponse().also {
            instance = it
        }
    }

    private fun retrofitBuild() : Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
           .client(okHttpClient)
           .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()


    private fun fullResponse(): ApiService {
        return retrofitBuild().create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

Specifically this is the part i am talking about

```
@Volatile
    private var instance : ApiService? = null
    fun getInstance() : ApiService = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        instance ?: fullResponse().also {
            instance = it
        }
    }
```

Now what i think what is happening over here: 
Before **Singleton** the response was successful but **instance** was not visible for other threads. That is why it was **null**. As i am using **coroutines** it might be running from different thread, after making the **singleton @volatile** which makes the **singleton** visible for all threads. When the program try to run from different thread and **@Volatile** has capability to access to all threads,which made program execute successfully without **null**